# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Skip images within div

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom, skip, imagesource

Hi i'm having below html structure,

```
<div id="main">
 <div class="contents">
  <div class="title">....</div>
  <div class="image"><img src="imagepath" /></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Using below code i'm collecting all it's contents.

```
$description = trim(@$html->find('div[id=main]', 0)->innertext);
```

Now i'm trying to remove images within `<div id="main"></div>`

so far i tried `@$html->find('div[class=image]', 0)->innertext = '';`

But no changes. Any solution to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, you want to use outertext:

```
$div = $html->find('#main', 0);
foreach($div->find('.image') as $img) $img->outertext = '';
```

Comment: It's you once again. It solved my problem. Thank you.